# Golang mongodb aggregation error : Pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field

Tags: mongodb, go

I want to get the count of grouped by name in the past of one month. When I try to run the below query in golang mongo client. I get the error:

`error:` A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field.

```
    cond := &bson.D{
        bson.E{Key: "$createTime", Value: bson.E{Key: "$gte", Value: time.Now().AddDate(0, -1, 0)}},
    }
    match := bson.D{{Key: "$match", Value: cond}}
    group := bson.D{{Key: "$group", Value: bson.D{
        {Key: "_id", Value: "$name"},
        {Key: "count", Value: bson.D{{Key: "$sum", Value: 1}}},
    }}}
    cursor, err := col.Aggregate(ctx, mongo.Pipeline{match, group})
```

I couldn't know how can I do?

Comment: I'm not familiar with go specific syntax, but if you render (see here https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/pretty-print-golang-pipelines/213173/3) the query (pipeline), I'm 99% sure you will see something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71571855/a-pipeline-stage-specification-object-must-contain-exactly-one-field?rq=2

Comment: Your pipeline gives different error. Fix the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the desired result by making the following adjustments:

- `$createTime` changed to `createTime`, I assume your field name does not start with `$`
- `bson.E{Key: "$gte", Value: time.Now().AddDate(0, -1, 0)}` changed to `bson.D{{Key: "$gte", Value: time.Now().AddDate(0, -1, 0)}}`

```
cond := &bson.D{
    bson.E{Key: "createTime", Value: bson.D{{Key: "$gte", Value: time.Now().AddDate(0, -1, 0)}}},
}
match := bson.D{{Key: "$match", Value: cond}}
group := bson.D{{Key: "$group", Value: bson.D{
    {Key: "_id", Value: "$name"},
    {Key: "count", Value: bson.D{{Key: "$sum", Value: 1}}},
}}}
cursor, err := col.Aggregate(context.TODO(), mongo.Pipeline{match, group})

if err != nil {
    log.Println("Error: ", err)
}
```

Some tips for debugging this kind of problems:

- always check the message of the error returned in the `err` variable
- you can enable raw db command logging in the following way:

```
uri := options.Client().ApplyURI(appSettings.MongoDbUri)

if appSettings.LogDatabaseCommands {
    cmdMonitor := &event.CommandMonitor{
        Started: func(_ context.Context, evt *event.CommandStartedEvent) {
            log.Print(evt.Command)
        },
    }
    uri.SetMonitor(cmdMonitor)
}
```